# How to set next actions when user click on the button in my Adaptive Card (using MS Teams and Action.Submit with id property for the text input)

Tags: javascript, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm struggling to indicate which option has been chosen by the user..

I've got the adaptive card in my notification bot that allows the user to choose the timer: either 3 minutes or 1 minute and click the button to submit their decision as below:

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "medium",
            "weight": "bolder",
            "text": "Hi Hooman!"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "style": "Person",
                            "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3647943215/d7f12830b3c17a5a9e4afcc370e3a37e_400x400.jpeg",
                            "size": "Small"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "auto"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "text": "I'm your personal Water Bot :)",
                            "wrap": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Now, set the timer for your water reminder!",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "Type minutes",
            "id": "id_minutes"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Start!"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4"
}
```

I am aware that I can somehow use the id property of the text input to indicate which option has been chosen by the user however I am lost where to go and what to do next to find that information and how to set the timer with my TimerTrigger function next.

Can anyone help please?!

[NOTE: I am very new to creating bots in Teams so please use a simple language to explain things!]

I found this blog: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

And tried to use this solution:

```
var txt = turnContext.activity.text;
var val = turnContext.activity.value;
// Check if the activity came from a submit action
if (!txt && val) {
    // Retrieve the data from the id_number field
    var num = parseFloat(val.id_number);
    // . . .
}
```

But not entirely sure where this should go (messageHandler.js? timerTrigger.js? teamsBot.js? or others?)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to do this inside the dialog in which you're sending the card.

Since you're new to bot building, might I suggest taking a few minutes to run through the [Create a basic bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cvs) quickstart? This will introduce some of the core concepts to you, including taking in user input. Once you understand the quickstart, you'll be able to look at the Adaptive Card documentation again and understand what's being done.

Comment: Thanks AP01. By the dialog do you mean my timerTrigger.js file? Which looks like this:

Comment: const notificationTemplate = require("./adaptiveCards/notification-default.json");
const { AdaptiveCards } = require("@microsoft/adaptivecards-tools");
const { notificationApp } = require("./internal/initialize");

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
  const timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
  for (const target of await notificationApp.notification.installations()) {
    await target.sendAdaptiveCard(
      AdaptiveCards.declare(notificationTemplate).render({
      notificationUrl: "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      })
    );
  }

Comment: Bots built with Bot Framework (which includes many Teams bots) have dialogs that contain the logic for a specific conversation. An example of this might be a travel booking bot. This bot many have a series of code files, each one containing the conversation steps needed to book a different form of transportation. One for buses, one for trains, one for aircraft, and so on. Your bot will interpret the user's input and direct them to the dialog. In your case, setting a timer might be one dialog.